# Value at position 6 in the NgModule.imports of AppModule is not a reference Value could not be determined statically

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

Im having an error where it wont implement the interface, ive tried fixing it but it wont.
i have been sitting on this problem for days and have tried all sorts of methods but i just cant seem to crack it.

Sourcecode:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { FrontpageComponent } from './frontpage/frontpage.component';
import { AdministratorComponent } from './administrator/administrator.component';
import { AdminCustomerComponent } from './admin-customer/admin-customer.component';
import { Ng2SearchPipeModule } from 'ng2-search-filter';
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
import { CategoryComponent } from './category/category.component';
import { BookComponent } from './book/book.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { ContactComponent } from './contact/contact.component';
import { CategoryDetailsComponent } from './category-details/category-details.component';
import { BookDetailsComponent } from './book-details/book-details.component';
import { LoanComponent } from './loan/loan.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {MatDatepickerModule} from '@angular/material/input';//error happens here 
 
    imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    FormsModule,
    Ng2SearchPipeModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,


    MatDatepickerModule,//and here

  ],
  providers: [DatePipe],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: It's should be:`import {MatDatepickerModule} from '@angular/material/datepicker';`. NOTE: in the docs of material, in API you can see the module import and the directory, e.g. for [datepicker](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/api)